# X3d scene having Multiple touchsensors,need to know which touchsensor is clcikes or selected?

Tags: html, x3d

I have an x3d scene that contains multiple touchsensor nodes.When i click a particular touchsensor node i need to get the details about the selected node.Please give me any kind of help.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give a different **DEF** name to each TouchSensor, then you can **ROUTE** to different events to distinguish which one the event comes from.

---

Full example: [multiple_touchsensors.x3dv](https://gist.github.com/cecilemuller/5720511)

Excerpt:

```
[...]
DEF touchsensor_1 TouchSensor {}
[...]
DEF touchsensor_2 TouchSensor {}
[...]

DEF a_script Script {
    eventIn     SFTime      obj_1_clicked
    eventIn     SFTime      obj_2_clicked

    directOutput TRUE
    url "javascript:

    function obj_1_clicked(){
        trace('The Box was clicked');
    }

    function obj_2_clicked(){
        trace('The Sphere was clicked');
    }

    "
}

ROUTE touchsensor_1.touchTime TO a_script.obj_1_clicked
ROUTE touchsensor_2.touchTime TO a_script.obj_2_clicked
```

Comment: I was unable to add the DEF field t the touchsensor node.and i all need to write this event handling in the javascript.